# How to open a PDF file in its associated application in a UWP application?

Tags: c#, file, uwp

I have a UWP application that contains a PDF file in a folder called Images and I need to open the file in its associated application on Windows (a browser or a PDF reader). I've seen all the similar questions posted here and came to the code below but it didn't work. Any suggestion?

```
    private async void nviHelp_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string pdfFile = @"Images\witmnlptbr.pdf";

        var file = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(pdfFile);

        if (file != null)
        {
            var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Launcher.LaunchFileAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher.launchfileasync?view=winrt-22621) will launch the default app associated with the specified file.  There are two things that you need to notice about this.

1. Make sure that the Build Action of the target file is set to content.

[image]

2. Make sure that the default app for the PDF file is set to the browser or the PDF reader in the Settings system.

[image]